# Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=my bundile id}

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, apple-sign-in

`Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=my bundile id}`

I have the same issue. I enabled the sign in with apple capability both developer console as well in Xcode, but the error still remains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue just now after I changed by bundle id and developer account. All the settings were correct in my developer account and on Xcode. This fixed it for me:

1. Go to the settings app
2. Tap your name at the top
3. Password & Security
4. Apps Using your Apple ID
5. Remove the app that's causing trouble

Comment: This worked for me when I was receiving error 7034. I have no idea why. I needed to add a popup explaining to users how to do this themselves on the error callback. I never even wanted sign in with apple in the first place but they refused app store acceptance until I had it. Very annoying apple!

Answer (score 20):

I found this issue when integrating apple sign-in in my project. I resolved this issue by following steps.

1. Go to project 'target'
2. Then select 'Signin & Capabilites'
3. Then select '+'
4. Then select 'Sign in with Apple'. Like this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZRlo.jpg
   Finally run your project & you will able to sign in with apple.

Comment: We're getting this error in TestFlight only. Capabilities are there for all configurations.

Answer (score 3):

The error code (7026) seems to indicate a missing capability but this wasn't the case for me as I hadn't touched my apps capabilities. I wasn't able to track down the exact cause of this issue but what appears to work is to try again with a different simulator and sign in. Then rerun the app on the original (problematic) simulator and it will work again.

Edit to clarify the comments below:
If you are getting a 7034 error code try the following. Go to appleid.apple.com find the problematic simulator and delete it from the "devices" section.

Comment: You reference this answer on a different question that is about 7034. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327156/log-in-with-apple-fails-on-simulator-but-works-on-personal-device?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment111998199_63327156

Comment: @livingtech you're correct appologies. I actually got 7034 error once more in the simulator and managed to fix it by going here https://appleid.apple.com/ finding the simulator and deleting it from the "devices" section.

Comment: Removing the simulator at appleid.apple.com did the trick! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Go here and remove the not healthy simulator => works for me. Thanks the support!

appleid.apple.com

[image]