# Log in with Apple fails on simulator, but works on personal device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am no longer able to log in with my Apple ID to my app on the Xcode simulator after it  was previously working as of few days ago. However, I am able to log in fine with a physical device. Sign in with Apple has been enabled for both debug and release. I'm pretty sure that I haven't made any changes my login view controller. After an attempted login, the console prints this:

Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7034 "(null)"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I left an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911917/authorization-failed-error-domain-akauthenticationerror-code-7026-null-use/63337693#63337693) which for me seems to work around this issue.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!