# How to solve Sign in with apple throws exception in iOS app built in Flutter platform?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-sign-in

There is a problem we are having since we tried to publish last update to our app. In this update, we added one new feature which is "Sign in with Apple".
Our app is developed in Flutter platform. For implementing the "Sign in with Apple" feature, we have added the following plugin in app and followed the instructions given exactly-
https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple

After completing all the implementation part, our "Sign in with Apple" worked for few days both in simulator and real device iPhone 7 plus. But suddenly, after few days, when I was running my project on Xcode, they asked me to login to xcode again. I logged in using the same account. Then just after that, whenever I am running the project and cliking the "Sign in with Apple" button, I am getting the following error-

Sign in with apple throws "Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=my bundile id}"

To solve this issue, we have followed some solutions mentioned here in the below links-

[Sign in with apple throws Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389908/sign-in-with-apple-throws-authorization-failed-error-domain-akauthenticationerr)

[Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=my bundile id}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911917/authorization-failed-error-domain-akauthenticationerror-code-7026-null-use)

In most of the solutions, they have mentioned to add "Sign in with Apple" in "Signin & Capabilites" section that we have already added. So, none of the solutions is working for us and we are having no idea to solve it yet.
So, It would be very nice, if you guide us what's actually our problem is and how to solve this to make this "Sign in with Apple" working perfectly.

Comment: Any updates on what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

SignIn with an apple a second time, it returns an encoded token and we will get the appleId and user name with help of the JwtDecoder decoder.

Check here
https://immublogpost.blogspot.com/2021/07/signin-with-apple-in-flutter.html